# issue on MaskedEditExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using ajax MaskedEditExtender Extender it's working fine but once's entering time i can not edited that textBox for chenging the value i want to select all value from textbox and change is done....and editing is notworking in any browser

my requirement is i need to edit  textbox using Backspace or detele .i m providing code

similar like editable textbox
   http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/maskededit/maskededit.aspx

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtscantime" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     ValidationGroup="save" runat="server" width="250px">
  </asp:TextBox>

      <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="mskscantimer"  
          ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False"   runat="server" TargetControlID="txtscantime"  
          UserTimeFormat="TwentyFourHour" MaskType="Time"  AcceptNegative="None"
          Mask="99:99"  >
     </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the issue(bug ) in ajax control toolkit 3.0

You will have to update your toolkit to 3.5 and it can be founded here

[Download link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475#DownloadId=116533)

Thanks to them that they have fixed this issue in 3.5

Comment: This solution sounds like good... I have to check it my self.